# Materials that work to show water has leaked in an area

Tags: roof, leak

In this question, the Questioner has a damp spot below but seen no sign of water on the framing/sheathing. [Roof Leak without any Visible Shingle Damage or Issue](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/247709/18078)

What would be a good material to dust onto the framing that would leave a track when water runs over it?

I thought perhaps chalk dust, or talcum powder. Flour seems inadvisable as it's pretty much spreading bug food. I know there are fancy "water indicating paints" used to show water at the bottom of oil tanks, but those seem rather expensive and specialized for the purpose.

Comment: Think any fine dust that is cheap would do, that sticks well to dry wood.  Problem would be covering the surface without having a lot of dust in the air.  Imagine this would be for a known time that the leak will occur.  Chalk line containers might be best, limited dust, good lines laid down.  Water should make a trace though the lines.

Comment: cool-aid drink mix .... sheet of paper with text printed by an inkjet printer should also work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your question you suggest **talcum or chalk**, and this is what I use under sinks, in cars etc..

**Kid's chalk** comes in a variety of colours, which is handy if you need to trace against a white background. You can dust it on or draw it on in horizontal lines.

Sometimes I'll wrap or tape on a piece of **tissue or kitchen towel**, when I don't have the above powders at hand or when it's difficult to blow the powder on with proper aim such as deep under a sink, or all around a piece of pipe.

I also use **soot dust** (from burning some paper or a scented burn stick from my spouse's yoga department) or **graphite** from a dispenser in areas where I need strong contrast against white, of if I have neither of the above at hand.

For a long lasting mark you could use **drywall setting compound**, which would mark the water trail and then harden for inspection much later. I haven't needed this, but always thought this trick could be of use somewhere. Possibly **cement or grout** could be used too.

The benefit of talcum or chalk, and to some degree soot, is that they can be used in small amounts *without too much worry about toxicity and lung irritation*. Uncured drywall, cement and grout powder are corrosive and the dusting should not be breathed in.

Comment: Not that it matters, but kids chalk, at least the fat ones used for drawing on the ground, is actually plaster