# How do I find a leak in the ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, leak, rain

We have a leak in the ceiling in my daughter's room. It only leaks during heavy rain. I went in the attic space above her room and don’t see any water up there (but I couldn't get super close) and the underside of the roof appears to be dry.

Could there be another source of the leak outside of the roof?

Comment: Yes, the water could be coming from anywhere. It's possible that it's coming from further up the roof than you'd expect, running down a rafter and getting to your daughter's ceiling that way. You may want to take a look at the shingles from the outside, too, to see if you see any signs of damage or things that "just don't look quite right".

Comment: This may help? https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/247740/18078 water runs downhill, so anywhere "above" directly over the point where you find it in the ceiling is suspect. It can travel a long way on framing from the point of entry until it decides to drip off, or it can drip directly down.

Comment: If lucky the water will leave a stain/discoloration on wood from where it comes in.  Unless up there during heavy rain, the chance of finding water/wetness is low.

Comment: How far from the exterior wall is the apparent leak?

Comment: How close to an outside wall is it? I had a real head-scratcher once, when it would only leak during intense rain. Turned out the plastic soffit holding the gutters would tilt slightly towards the house when heavy with rain, and pour inside.