How can I tell if water damage in an unfinished attic is new?
How do I tell if water damage in an unfinished attic is new or old?  House is 77 years old.

See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/247740/18078 for some techniques to note new water ingress.


Check for residual moisture. Feel whether it's damp or cool, or use a moisture meter.

Check for fresh mold or mildew. Does anything rub off? Does it have a strong odor?

Inspect for dust, insect evidence, and other debris. Obviously older damage will not be clean on the surface.

Set up a test. Something like paper towel secured in position will make it very clear whether it's been wet since installation due to deformity and staining.




Go to the attic during/after a rain storm and look for water

